# Bootstrap absolute positioned div not showing correctly above navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu from the navbar, triggered by a toggle button. I added a triangle above the navbar-collapse to show it pointing to the trigger button. It works fine on larger screens but on mobile it keeps getting pushed behind the navbar. I've tried working with z-index but to no avail.

http://www.bootply.com/g8d0nLzlIE

I've made the triangle on mobile in grey (instead of white like on desktop) to show contrast.

Comment: Hi Rachel, I usually see you answering questions, here you have one of your own :) Why don't you reset the `overflow` rule on `.navbar-collapse.in` to `visible`? 
`.navbar-collapse.in {overflow-y: visible;}`

Comment: Hey @UncaughtTypeError I had to take a break from answering because I'm working on a new project ;) Thanks so much for this idea! It works. Can you put it up as an answer so I can mark it as one?

Comment: Sure, no problem - added :)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Would you happen to know how to get the triangle to show up with the transition of the menu load, instead of after a second delay?

Comment: You could `fix` it instead and take it out the natural flow of the document, it's a tad hacky though, but try this: `.navbar-collapse:before {border-bottom: 20px solid #fff; border-left: 20px solid transparent; border-right: 20px solid transparent; top: 75px; content: ""; position: fixed; left: 28px; margin-left: -10px; width: 0;height: 0;}` - may stil point you in the right direction

Comment: Yes, that works beautifully! Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Happy to be of assistance, Rachel. Make sure you test that one thoroughly though ;)

Comment: Yup. If you scroll, it disappears, but then it comes back when you scroll back up, which I think looks pretty cool ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile resolutions, you can reset the `overflow` rule declared for `.navbar-collapse.in` to `visible`.

**CSS**

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```